# Are blink tags not supported on modern browsers?

Tags: html, firefox, browser

Today (please don't kill me) I used a `<blink>` tag.

It was just a test: I needed some text to put into some code to check that it was correctly serving HTML, so I sent `Hello world!` wrapped in a `<blink>` tag.

I know that what I did was wrong and I promise not to do it again.

I was rather surprised, though, to discover that Firefox 34 didn't actually blink the text! Is this to be expected? Do Chrome and IE also refuse to be so crass? Is it, technically speaking, a failure to implement the HTML specification?

Obviously I would never use `<blink>` tags in real code. But I do remember that they blew my tiny mind back in the 1990s when they first appeared, and I feel like I've lost part of my adolescence, which is a little painful even when you know it's a bad part of your adolescence that's gone.

Comment: It was deprecated a while back

Comment: There was a rumor that every time someone uses <blink> tag, a kitten dies so browsers stopped supporting it.

Comment: When you saw the result! Did you actually blink yourself, the two may have the same blink frequency and it may appear as an optical illusion that it doesn't work, where in fact it does work. or you can blame yourself according to this thought experiment. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger%27s_cat

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It isn't supported in firefox since 23.0, none of the other browsers support it any more (or never have)

- Chrome: Not supported
- Firefox: Not supported since 23.0
- Safari: Not supported

**https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/blink**

From above source:

**Deprecated**

This feature has been removed from the Web standards. Though some browsers may still support it, it is in the process of being dropped. Do not use it in old or new projects. Pages or Web apps using it may break at any time.

Comment: Support also existed in Netscape and in Opera (not clear up to which version, but surely not any modern version).

Comment: It seems not to be supported in opera since 15.0 @JukkaK.Korpela